# GPU Passthrough using IOMMU

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine

So im attempting to setup a VM on my debian(buster) linux distro currently when attempting to isolate my nvidia gtx 760

so ive currently followed these steps

i ran "lspci -nnk" anf got my gpus device ids being

video: 10de:1187

audio: 10de:0e0a

i then went to the file

"/etc/initramfs-tools/modules"

and appended this to the end of it

"vfio_pci ids=10de:1187,10de:0e0a" ( i later appended it to /etc/default/grub resulting in it looking like this "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nouvea.modeset=0 iommu=pt intel_iommu=on vfio-pci.ids=10de:1187,10de:0e0a""

then i ran

"update-initramfs -u"

after all this the gpu is still being taken control of by "nouveau" and i cant figure out how to resolve it

lspci -nnk

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 760] [10de:1187] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GK104 [GeForce GTX 760] [1458:360b]
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
Kernel modules: nouveau

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:0e0a] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GK104 HDMI Audio Controller [1458:360b]
Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

/etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nouvea.modeset=0 iommu=pt intel_iommu=on vfio-pci.ids=10de:1187,10de:0e0a"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

/etc/modules

```
vfio
vfio_pci
vfio_iommu_type1
vfio_virqfd

firewire-sbp2
```

IOMMU Groups

```
IOMMU Group 1:
    00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 760] [10de:1187] (rev a1)
    01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:0e0a] (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after running grub-install

and restarting for somereason its working perfectly...

i dont understand but im not going to complain

Comment: You need to restart in order to a) run the newer initramfs image you built, b) activate the grub bootloader options you changed, and c) activate the modules you added (unless you run the `modprobe` command).
To do all that manually on a running system probably wouldn't work, I don't know what issues would come from attempting to disable a running and active gpu. Usually when dealing with a bootloader, initramfs or kernel change, you reboot. Sometimes kernels can be changed over without a reboot (ie: `ksplice`), but that's more for servers.